# cannot install ToR service in kali

Tags: installation, kali-linux, apt, tor

```
apt install tor
```

I am getting this error:

> Package tor is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>
> This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source.
>
> E: Package 'tor' has no installation candidate

Comment: Hi Shehab, can you please show in your question (by [editting](https://superuser.com/posts/1578244/edit)) what command you run that show you this error? And also maybe the results you get from websearches when you lookup that error message? That would help people to understand what you've tried so far and why that didn't work.

Comment: apt install tor

Comment: And also maybe the results you get from websearches when you lookup that error message?

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`.